# Shifting focus() - Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the following code in Angular 5:

```
<select class="abc" (change)="items($event)"  required>

            <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                  <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
          </select>
```

When a user selects any particular of the above option, the focus goes onto the selected option. I'm trying to get any selected option out of focus(after the user selects any option) and would to like to shift focus on a different element of the DOM(if required).
I tried `getElementById with focus()` but it doesn't seem to work.

```
items(event)
  {
    ABC Code;
    Shifting focus code goes here;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working solution in Angular way using **`Renderer2`**

**HTML:**

```
<select class="abc" (change)="change()"  required>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>


<input type="text" id="myInput">
<input type="text">
```

**Component:**

```
import { Component, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  constructor(public renderer2: Renderer2){

  }

  change(){
     let onElement = this.renderer2.selectRootElement('#myInput');
 onElement.focus();
  }

 }
```

[**Here is a working DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vfjfrq?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: @Sanket Sawant, please check my answer

Comment: Hi Sravan,Thanks for the working demo. I really need to shift the focus on the whole DOM as I want to make `scroll bar` on webpage work .What should be done in that case?

Comment: @SanketSawantm, means didnt get you

Comment: For example: When we reload any webpage, where is the default focus() on? On which element? Likewise what should I do to get that default focus() on the whole webpage ?

Comment: after the select element is selected, the default focus will go as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your different element is this:

```
<input type="text" #inputText>
```

Then you can try this:

```
<select class="abc" (change)="inputText.focus()"  required>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Tried this but this is not shifting focus

Answer (score 0):

This is standard Javascript and as you can see it works, if you have an error you need to provide a sandbox reproducing the said error. Pseudo-code isn't enough to identify the issue.

```js
function focusInput(value) {
  document.querySelector('input#input-' + value).focus();
}
```

```html
<select onchange="focusInput(this.value)" palceholder="select an input to focus">
  <option value="0">Input 0</option>
  <option value="1">Input 1</option>
  <option value="2">Input 2</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="input-0" placeholder="Input 0" style="display: block;">
<input type="text" id="input-1" placeholder="Input 1" style="display: block;">
<input type="text" id="input-2" placeholder="Input 2" style="display: block;">
```

Comment: is it ok. if we use query Selector in angular app?

Comment: For focusing an element, yes it is. But nothing prevents you from using a template variable, the `Renderer2`, or any other way Angular provides. I'm just showing that this simple code works on any given device.